# tensorflowjs: How to extends tf.layers.conv2d when writing tensorflowjs custom layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I need to write a custom layer of tensorflowjs to import my model. In the original python code, this is implemented by extensions Conv2D, but this seems not to be possible in the tfjs code. Ask for help.

**Error message**
[image]

I am new to tensorflow and I would like to know how to convert this custom layer into tfjs code, this has been bothering me for a long time, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is python cunstom layer code.

```py
from keras.utils import conv_utils
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine import InputSpec
from keras.layers import Conv2D


class PConv2D(Conv2D):
    def __init__(self, *args, n_channels=3, mono=False, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.input_spec = [InputSpec(ndim=4), InputSpec(ndim=4)]

    def build(self, input_shape):        
        """Adapted from original _Conv() layer of Keras        
        param input_shape: list of dimensions for [img, mask]
        """

        if self.data_format == 'channels_first':
            channel_axis = 1
        else:
            channel_axis = -1

        if input_shape[0][channel_axis] is None:
            raise ValueError('The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. Found `None`.')

        self.input_dim = input_shape[0][channel_axis]

        # Image kernel
        kernel_shape = self.kernel_size + (self.input_dim, self.filters)
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=kernel_shape,
                                      initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                      name='img_kernel',
                                      regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                                      constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
        # Mask kernel
        self.kernel_mask = K.ones(shape=self.kernel_size + (self.input_dim, self.filters))

        if self.use_bias:
            self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.filters,),
                                        initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                                        name='bias',
                                        regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
                                        constraint=self.bias_constraint)
        else:
            self.bias = None
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
        '''
        We will be using the Keras conv2d method, and essentially we have
        to do here is multiply the mask with the input X, before we apply the
        convolutions. For the mask itself, we apply convolutions with all weights
        set to 1.
        Subsequently, we set all mask values >0 to 1, and otherwise 0
        ''' 

        # Both image and mask must be supplied
        if type(inputs) is not list or len(inputs) != 2:
            raise Exception('PartialConvolution2D must be called on a list of two tensors [img, mask]. Instead got: ' + str(inputs))

        # Create normalization. Slight change here compared to paper, using mean mask value instead of sum
        normalization = K.mean(inputs[1], axis=[1,2], keepdims=True)
        normalization = K.repeat_elements(normalization, inputs[1].shape[1], axis=1)
        normalization = K.repeat_elements(normalization, inputs[1].shape[2], axis=2)

        # Apply convolutions to image
        img_output = K.conv2d(
            (inputs[0]*inputs[1]) / normalization, self.kernel, 
            strides=self.strides,
            padding=self.padding,
            data_format=self.data_format,
            dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate
        )

        # Apply convolutions to mask
        mask_output = K.conv2d(
            inputs[1], self.kernel_mask, 
            strides=self.strides,
            padding=self.padding,            
            data_format=self.data_format,
            dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate
        )

        # Where something happened, set 1, otherwise 0        
        mask_output = K.cast(K.greater(mask_output, 0), 'float32')

        # Apply bias only to the image (if chosen to do so)
        if self.use_bias:
            img_output = K.bias_add(
                img_output,
                self.bias,
                data_format=self.data_format)

        # Apply activations on the image
        if self.activation is not None:
            img_output = self.activation(img_output)

        return [img_output, mask_output]

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        if self.data_format == 'channels_last':
            space = input_shape[0][1:-1]
            new_space = []
            for i in range(len(space)):
                new_dim = conv_utils.conv_output_length(
                    space[i],
                    self.kernel_size[i],
                    padding=self.padding,
                    stride=self.strides[i],
                    dilation=self.dilation_rate[i])
                new_space.append(new_dim)
            new_shape = (input_shape[0][0],) + tuple(new_space) + (self.filters,)
            return [new_shape, new_shape]
        if self.data_format == 'channels_first':
            space = input_shape[2:]
            new_space = []
            for i in range(len(space)):
                new_dim = conv_utils.conv_output_length(
                    space[i],
                    self.kernel_size[i],
                    padding=self.padding,
                    stride=self.strides[i],
                    dilation=self.dilation_rate[i])
                new_space.append(new_dim)
            new_shape = (input_shape[0], self.filters) + tuple(new_space)
            return [new_shape, new_shape]
```

Here is my tfjs code

```js
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import {convOutputLength, deconvLength, normalizeArray} from '@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/utils/conv_utils';
import { InputSpec } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/engine/topology';


class PConv2D extends tf.layers.Layer {
  constructor(config) {
    super({config});
    // TODO(bileschi): Can we point to documentation on masking here?
    this.supportsMasking = true;
    this.inputSpec = [new InputSpec({ ndim: 4 }),new InputSpec({ ndim: 4 })];
    console.log(this.activation)
    if (config != undefined)
    {
        console.log(config.filters);
        this.kernelSize = config.kernelSize;
        this.filters = config.filters;
        this.strides = config.strides;
        this.padding = config.padding;
        this.dataFormat = config.dataFormat;
        this.dilationRate = config.dilationRate;
        this.useBias = config.useBias;
        this.biasInitializer = config.biasInitializer;
        this.biasConstraint = config.biasConstraint;
        this.kernelInitializer = config.kernelInitializer;
        this.kernelRegularizer = config.kernelRegularizer;
        this.activation = config.activation;

    }
    console.log(config);
    //console.log(config.name);
    console.log(this.input_spec);
  }
  build(inputShape) {

    const channelAxis =
        this.dataFormat === 'channelsFirst' ? 1 : inputShape.length - 1;
    if (inputShape[channelAxis] == null) {
      throw new ValueError(
          'The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. ' +
          'Found `None`.');
    }

    const inputDim = inputShape[0][channelAxis];
    const kernelShape = this.kernelSize.concat([inputDim,this.filters]);

    // Image kernel

    this.kernel = this.addWeight(
        'img_kernel', kernelShape, 'float32', this.kernelInitializer,
        this.kernelRegularizer, true, this.kernelConstraint);

    this.kernel_mask = tf.ones(kernelShape);

    if (this.useBias) {
      this.bias = this.addWeight(
          'bias', [this.filters], 'float32', this.biasInitializer,
          this.biasRegularizer, true, this.biasConstraint);
      };

    this.built = true;
    this.inputSpec = [new InputSpec({ ndim: 4 }),new InputSpec({ ndim: 4 })];
    //this.inputSpec = [{ndim: 4},{ndim: 4}];


    };

  computeOutputShape(inputShape) {
    const space = (this.dataFormat === 'channelsLast') ?
      inputShape[0].slice(1, inputShape.length - 1) :
      inputShape.slice(2);

    const newSpace = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < space.length; ++i) {
        const newDim = convOutputLength(
            space[i], this.kernelSize[i], this.padding, this.strides[i],
            typeof this.dilationRate === 'number' ? this.dilationRate :
                                                    this.dilationRate[i]);
        newSpace.push(newDim);
    }
    let outputShape = [inputShape[0]];

  if (this.dataFormat === 'channelsLast') {
        outputShape = outputShape[0].concat(newSpace);
        outputShape.push(this.filters);
      } else {
        outputShape.push(this.filters);
        outputShape = outputShape.concat(newSpace);
      }

    return [outputShape,outputShape];

  }

  call(inputs, kwargs) {


    return tf.tidy(() => {
      // if (inputs.length !== 2) {
      //     throw new ValueError(
      //         'PartialConvolution2D must be called on a list of two tensors [img, mask]');
      // }

      let normalization = tf.mean(inputs[1], [1,2],true)
      normalization = normalization.tile([1, inputs[0].shape[1], inputs[0].shape[2],1])


      let a = tf.mul(inputs[0],inputs[1])
      a = tf.mul(a,normalization)

      let img_outputs = tf.conv2d(
          a,this.filters, this.kernel.read(),
          this.strides, this.padding, this.dataFormat,this.dilationRate);

      let mask_outputs = tf.conv2d(
          inputs[1],this.filters, this.kernel.read(),
          this.strides, this.padding, this.dataFormat,this.dilationRate);

      mask_outputs = K.cast(K.greater(mask_output, 0), 'float32')

      if (this.activation != null) {
        img_outputs = this.activation.apply(img_outputs);
      }
      return [img_outputs, mask_outputs];

    });


  }

  /**
   * If a custom layer class is to support serialization, it must implement
   * the `className` static getter.
   */
  static get className() {
    return 'PConv2D';
  }
  getConfig() {
    const config = super.getConfig();
    //Object.assign(config, {kernelSize: this.kernelSize});
    console.log(config)
    return config;
  }
}
tf.serialization.registerClass(PConv2D);  // Needed for serialization.

export function pconv2d() {
  return new PConv2D();
}

var myTester = new pconv2d()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by

> var myTester = new pconv2d()

the pconv2d needs the kernelSize and the filters. Others properties of the config object passed as parameter are optional

`new pconv2d({kernelSize: number, filters: number})` will fix the issue.

But as done in the case of the python layer, `pconv2d` can inherit from `tf.layers.conv2d`.

Here is a simple example to demonstrate it

```
class pconv2d extends tf.layers.conv2d {
  static className = 'MyCustomLayer';

  constructor(config) {
    super(config);
    // add other initialization
  }
  // add computation of the layer
}
tf.serialization.registerClass(pconv2d);
a = tf.ones([16, 16, 16, 16])
b = new MyCustomLayer({kernelSize: 2, filters: 2}).apply(a)
b.print()
```